# How to get the value of input field by custom attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm total beginner in jquery.

I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/0xLqhufd/2/

```
<body>
<div>
<input type="text" person="firstName" value="John">
<input type="text" person="birthDate" value="September 1st, 2000">
</div>
</body>
```

But I got only blank in alert :

```
$('input[person]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
  }
);
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own custom tags use html5 [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In void elements, using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) would be inappropriate. Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead. `input[type=text]` is a void element, that means it cannot have any child nodes inside of it including `text nodes`.

```
$('input[person]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0xLqhufd/3/)

Answer (score 2):

As said on the jQuery documentation ...

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts

Use .val() instead.

```
$('input[person]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
  }
);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0xLqhufd/5/)**

Comment: It is always good to include a working example in your answer. I have included it.

Answer (score 1):

input has .val() to read values

```
$('input[person]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());//will read input value
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a answer for your Doubt.

You have to change the Script which you have used as below.

```
$('input[person]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
  }
);
```

Please update me whether you find my code is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Hey you can use like this:-
   input "type=text" tags have the values not text.
   that's why you have to use .val() instead of .text().

   $('input[person]').each(function(index) {
       alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
   });
```